# Search, and display results from a text document in java

Tags: java, search

I'm trying to search a text document in Java for a user defined input, below is my current code. All this code is doing is telling me that whatever I search is in the document but I'm puzzled on how to display the actual results. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
String userSearch = ""; int val = 0;
while(!userSearch.matches("quit"))
{
    System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched for");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
    userSearch = input.next();

    while(file.hasNextLine())           
    {
        String line = file.nextLine();
        if(line.contains(userSearch))
        {
            System.out.println(line.contains(userSearch));
            val = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            val = 0;
            continue;
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you expand on your requirements, specifically, what type of output are you desiring and how your current code does not meet your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently when you found something, you call
`System.out.println(line.contains(userSearch));`
which as far as I know would print either "true" or "false" as String.contains(String) should return a boolean value.
To print the whole line just use `System.out.println(line);`
Or what would you like to see instead?

And I do not know what your `val` variable is for, but if it just says "result found" or "not found" you could use boolean. If you want to count the results, write `var++;` when it found something and nothing if the line does not contain the result. It's not about your question, but maybe useful too.

Comment: I feel really silly for not working that one out. Thank you very much for the help! I needed it to print the line. I managed to get it working in a while statement. Thanks again!

Comment: So if I could help you would you mind accepting the answer? It improves both our reputation score and shows the community that your question is answered. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

class person`private int age ; private person`age =24;`

Public clasa Test`public static void main(string[]args`person p = new person();System.out.println(p.age);

Comment: How is that even remotely related to the question?